# Spring OAuth2 Implementation - A redirect is required to get the users approval

Tags: spring, spring-oauth2

I know this question has been asked more than a few times and I have read over all of the answers but am still having an issue.  Basically, I am trying to setup an OAuth2 RestTemplate but am receiving the error (like so many others) when attempting to use the RestTemplate to make a getForEntity request:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.UserRedirectRequiredException: A redirect is required to get the users approval
```

Hoping someone can tell me what I am doing wrong.  Here is my configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class OAuth2Configuration
{
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2ClientContext oauth2Context;

    @Value("${test.oauth.key}")
    private String key;

    @Value("${test.oauth.secret}")
    private String secret;

    @Value("${test.auth.url}")
    private String authUrl;

    @Value("${test.token.url}")
    private String tokenUrl;

    /**
     * Returns an OAuth2 protected resource connection to test
     *
     * @return the oauth2 protected resource
     */
    @Bean
    public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails test()
    {
        // Create a new authorization code resource details object
        AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails details = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();

        // Set the information on the authorization code resource details object
        details.setId("java_server");
        details.setClientId(key);
        details.setClientSecret(secret);
        details.setUserAuthorizationUri(authUrl);
        details.setAccessTokenUri(tokenUrl);

        // Return the authorization code resource details object
        return details;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a rest template for test
     *
     * @return the rest template
     */
    @Bean(name = "testRestTemplate")
    public OAuth2RestTemplate testRestTemplate()
    {
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(test(), oauth2Context);
    }
}
```

This is the beginning of my base test class:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
public abstract class AbstractJUnitTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests
{
    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2ClientContextFilter clientContextFilter;

    @Autowired
    private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

    // Define protected class variables
    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    /**
     * Ensure the mock mvc framework has the spring security filter chain in it
     */
    @Before
    public void setup()
    {
        // Initialize the mock mvc
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
                .addFilters(
                        new RequestContextFilter(),
                        new DelegatingFilterProxy(clientContextFilter),
                        new DelegatingFilterProxy(springSecurityFilterChain))
                .build();
    }
    ...
}
```

And I have this line in my http security config:

```
<security:custom-filter ref="oauth2ClientContextFilter" after="SECURITY_CONTEXT_FILTER" />
```

Here is my service class that attempts to make the call:

```
@Service("testService")
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService
{
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("testRestTemplate")
    private OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate;

    /**
     * ${@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public List<Person> listPeople() throws Exception
    {
        ResponseEntity<String> sample = restTemplate.getForEntity(
                myEndpoint, String.class);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!  I am hoping it is just something dumb that I am missing but for whatever reason, I can't see it and therefore need help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of grant are you using?

Comment: Authorization code